# Playing video in Android app widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way to play video in Android App widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with the default home screen manager anyway.

Only these UI widgets can be used in an app widget:
AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html